# How can A and not A be both true when using static_assert

Tags: c++, templates, instantiation, constexpr, static-assert

A very confusing situation involving some constexpr and type traits led me to think the value of an expression is true, when in fact it was both true and false.

https://godbolt.org/z/McYMvxasT

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct S {

    constexpr int f() const {
        constexpr bool t = std::is_same_v<double, double>;
        static_assert(t);
        static_assert(!t);
        //static_assert(false);

        return 0;
    }

    static const int t = f();
};

int main() {
    //S<int> s;
    //std::cout << S<int>::t;

    return 0;
}
```

I know that if f() never gets instantiated then static_asserts are skipped but this hypothesis is rejected by uncommenting the line `static_assert(false)` which **does** fail. Is this a compiler bug?

Comment: Compilers are not required to do anything with templates that are never instantiated, so I doubt it's a bug. Seems more like GCC just treats `static_assert(false);` special. Clang gives errors even without the instantiation and MSVC will not error even when uncommenting the last `static_assert`

Comment: BTW clang complains about `static_assert(!t)` just fine. GCC tends to ignore uninstantiated templates, but i assume if you have something hardcoded like that, it treats it in some special way (i.e. i can think of some compiler bugs being filed just because GCC ignores apparent expressions like `static_assert(false);` and it was altered to check them unconditionally)

Comment: @UnholySheep MSVC will report an error when you use `/permissive-` to tell it to follow the C++ standard's template parsing rule https://godbolt.org/z/Todr8PjGG

Comment: Tangential: It's not the case with `bool`, but in general it's possible for both `x` and `!x` to be true if `x` is an object of some user-defined class type that overloads both `operator bool` and `operator !`, in such a way that `!(static_cast<bool>(x))` and `!x` disagree. You probably shouldn't write your class in such a way, but there's nothing in the standard that prevents you from doing so.

Comment: For gcc if a template has any kind of non trivial expression evaluation is delayed until the template is instantiated. In your case the `std::is_same_v<double, double>;` possibly might have to deduce additional template arguments that depend on `T` so it might not even be possible to evaluate without knowing `T`. Gcc doesn't invest any time finding out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A template which is not instantiated and which has no well-formed instantiation is ill-formed with no diagnostic required. The program is invalid but the compiler is not required to diagnose it.

Comment: WTF? You can hardly include anything from the STL without having a template that isn't instatiated. Where does the standard say that not instantiating a template is ill-formed? The only part I can accept as true in this answer is *"the compiler is not required to diagnose it"*.

Comment: "with no well-formed instantiation" meaning that no possible instantiation is well-formed, not that it wasn't instantiated. Do you have a suggested edit for clarity?

Comment: No suggestion and now I think it's even more wrong. A template, even with no well-formed instattiation, requires diagnostics IF it is instantiated. But your statement gives the compiler permission to ignore any errors no matter what just because there is no well-formed instatiation. A fact that would require a lot of diagnostic in general to conclude in the first place. It's the fact that the template is not instantiated that means no diagnostic is required.

Comment: You are correct. Instantiated but ill-formed (usually) would require a diagnostic. The way I worded it would include that so it is worth an edit. To my sensibilities, that was clear from context, but I'm happy to be explicit.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow please see the edit and see if this is more clear.

Comment: It might be worth noting that this is not because we want such code to still compile but that diagnosing this quickly becomes extremely hard if not even undecidable.

Answer (score 1):

It's not both true and false: it's simply not instantiated, so it's not evaluated. If you uncomment the two calls in main, it'll trigger the error.